# Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Loader in C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingCart\
library\Zend\Loader.php on line 31

zf create action add Index
```

When i try to create an Action in my Controller, I get this error. When I commented out my

```
;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

in my application.ini I get this error now.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function search() on a non-object in C:\xampp\php\
PEAR\Zend\Tool\Project\Provider\Action.php on line 92
```

Comment: well, have you tried to find all the places where you could have included the Zend_Loader?

Comment: @regilero: its included just in two places... one in application.ini and another in the index.php... its a start new scratch project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove or comment on this line from application.ini

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

and then

```
zf create action add
```

Note: I have removed the Index Controller, the action would created in Index Controller.